# Emacs indent with tabs to 2 columns

Tags: indentation, cc-mode, ruby-mode, tabs

Current with C, Javascript, Ruby, etc. when inserting a block with `{` `<RETURN>`, Emacs automatically indents the next line, but it does so with spaces. How do I change this behavior to tab characters? The follow is my configuration.

```
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
```

This sets the indention level to 2 (for C and Ruby, but strangely 4 for Javascript), but it still inserts spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: @lawlist Okay, thanks for the advice. I'll vote to move this to emacs.stackexange.com.

Comment: @lawlist If we drive all Emacs questions away, we'll never have people answering them either. That's not a good long-term solution to that problem. Emacs as computer software is absolutely on topic here. In fact, migrating to Beta sites is [typically not done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site), as these sites should grow organically, and not be fed by pulling questions off other sites where they would've been equally on topic.

Comment: I migrated this one as an exception for now, but let's not make this the default procedure. In fact, @lawlist, when mentioning other sites, you should at least mention that the question should not be just posted there *again*, but rather that the OP should *flag it for migration* if they didn't get an answer within, say, two days.

Comment: I'm guessing you have something overriding the default values either later in your init file or in a mode hook.

Comment: Use `C-h v` `indent-tabs-mode` from one of the buffers in question to check its *actual* value in that buffer. As Dan says, presumably some other config is overriding your default.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby editing mode defines `ruby-indent-tabs-mode` and sets `indent-tabs-mode` to that value when the mode is invoked.  The default for this is `nil`.  To fix your problem, set this variable instead.

This seems like a bug to me.  There's no reason Ruby needs its own special setting for this.

Note also that `c-basic-offset` doesn't affect Ruby.  Ruby has `ruby-indent-level`.  It's a bit of an Emacs oddity that modes must provide their own variables for basic indentation.